# Get back to the first screen of my iPhone app after transitioning through five screens

Tags: iphone

I'm using multiple screens in my app. I wrote code for the moving from the first screen to the second screen, the second screen to the third screen, and so on up to the fifth screen.

Now I want to jump to the first screen from the fifth screen, but I want to do this without creating another instance of the first screen, as that would cause memory problems.

Please suggest what to do in this case?

Answer (score 2):

[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

[self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] animated:YES];

You can use second line code then verify the index of view controller.

and you have memory problem so please verify the any object release or not.

Answer (score 0):

if you use a UINavigationController

```
 [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES
```

Comment: i havent use UINavigationController,i have used UIViewController

Comment: how you got to first Screen to fifth screen then? as modalView?

Answer (score 0):

Go through this best answer for you  [UINavigation controller](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)