# last screen to first screen in iphone

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iphone get back tothe main screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5789436/iphone-get-back-tothe-main-screen)

I have created one iPhone application. I'm using multiple screens in my app. I wrote the code for the moving from first screen to second screen, second screen to third screen up to the fifth screen. Now I want to jump to the first screen from the fifth screen. But I want to do this without creating another instance of the first screen, as it will bring up memory problems.

Please suggest what to do in this case?

i havent use UINavigationControoler. i have used UIViewController.....

Comment: why repeat question when your previous question gets enough attention..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5789436/iphone-get-back-tothe-main-screen

Comment: Just asking, why you are not using UINavigationController when what you are doing can be easily be done with it?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `navigationController` property of `UIViewController`

So use the below code to go back to the first screen (your root controller).

Call it from your last `UIViewController` inherited class

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```