# Iphone dev: How can I go back to my startpage?

Tags: iphone, navigation

In my App the user has to navigate trough 3 different views:
for example: Dashboard -> DamageAcc -> Damage.
In the Damage view the user can sent a damage to the server. After sending I would like to show the Dashboard again.
I tried to do this the way I navigated from Dashboard to DamageAcc and from DamageAcc to Damage.

```
 if(self.dashboardController == nil)
        {

            DashboardController *viewTwo = [[DashboardController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Dashboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];


            self.dashboardController = viewTwo;

            [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];

            [viewTwo release];
        }
```

But my program says, that it doesn't know the DashboardController.
I also imported it but this didn't help. So I tried to do a @class DashboardController but this didn't help, too.

Does anybody know what I can do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Get back to the first screen of my iPhone app after transitioning through five screens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5789436/iphone-get-back-tothe-main-screen)

```
 [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]
```